# How to connect 7-segment 4-digits display with Pi?

Tags: gpio, python, display, rpi.gpio, led

I would like to connect [such a 7-segment 4-digits](http://www.ebay.fr/itm/251718021572?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) display (with common anode) to the Raspberry Pi:

[image]

**What's the simplest way to do it with Python for example?**
Do I need the `RPi.GPIO` package?
**Is there a high-level way to display some numbers?** i.e. just like this:

```
SegmentDisplay.Print(23)  # will display "0023"
```

instead of low-level programming like:

```
GPIO.output(17, True)    # manually select which LED segments to display 
GPIO.output(18, True)    # ...
...
```

Comment: If nothing is really possible directly with such a simple 4-digit display, is there a solution with a I2C 4-digit display : http://www.adafruit.com/products/878 ?

Comment: What color is the display and what if any numbers are on it?

Comment: So no real solution to work with this non-I2C display?? So sad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple solution for a raw display like you linked to. That requires multiplexing which requires constant processing to maintain the display.  Perhaps with a threaded library you could make something acceptable but I don't know if something like that exists.

As an alternative you could use the [Adafruit LCD display with I2C interface](https://www.adafruit.com/products/878).  Adafruit has a [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/matrix-7-segment-led-backpack-with-the-raspberry-pi) for using it with the Raspberry Pi and has a [Python library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code) on github that seems to be what you want.

It even has [example code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_LEDBackpack/ex_7segment_clock.py).

Comment: Thanks, that might be the best indeed. Do you know where we can find this Adafruit display in Europe? (importing from Adafruit USA is so expensive and long shipping!)

Comment: Hmmm, [look at this](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/7segment-serial-display-green).  They refer to the Arduino, which I think uses 5V logic, but in  the specs it says "unregulated", which I *presume* means you could use 3.3V for it.  I know the Adafruit things like this allow you to use 5V power but 3.3V logic.  I'm no electronics guru but there are a few around here, so you might want to ask a specific question about that or on  [EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).   Found by searching `i2c 7-segment Europe`, BTW.

Comment: Actually if you look toward the bottom [here](https://github.com/sparkfun/Serial7SegmentDisplay/wiki/Hardware%20Specifications) the supply voltage is 2.4 - 5.5V so I think you are almost certainly good to go with that.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks ! This module seems great. It is a `SparkFun` part (I think they have the schematics on GitHub). Do you know how to interface it from Python? Will it be the same that the Arduino tutorial?

Comment: I'm not really a python user, but you would probably want to use the `smbus` library to interface with I2C.   I am sure with a combination of  experimentation and deduction from the sparkfun github docs/code it could be worked out, it looks pretty straightforward.  If you have not done something like this before it may seem a bit daunting at first.   You have to get a feel for how the communication works.

Comment: More generally, does lighting a LED need continuous action from the RPi ? Or just a single action like Set LED on / set LED off, and then nothing more?

Comment: If you are using a display like the adafruit with the ht16k33 i2c driver the Raspberry Pi does need to continually maintain the LEDs it only sends commands to change the display.

Comment: Do you think this SparkFun I2C display will work too? https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-serial-7-segment-display  Looking for a Python way to do it!

Comment: The Sparkfun display uses an Atmel AVR instead of the ht16k33 to drive the LEDs so the Raspberry Pi libraries from Adafruit probably won't work with it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://projects.drogon.net/7-segment-led-display-for-the-raspberry-pi/) example does not use Python but covers a lot of good points.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I'm still hoping there is a high-level Python library that allows to do that :)  (instead of low-level lighting some LEDs on/off)

Comment: Just one problem : `Any down-sides? Well the overhead of keeping the display updated is between 15 and 20% of the CPU usage on my Pi!` ... There surely should be a nicer solution, don't you think so ?

Comment: @Basj Wow. 20% CPU usage for keeping a display updated. I'm genuinely surprised. Are you running an RPI or RPI2?

Comment: @Joseph That's from the author.  The issue is probably that there evidently needs to be a 60/s loop "to prevent flicker".  Doing this completely in userland with python is inevitably going to be at the "inefficient" end of the spectrum.   And there are more than a dozen wires involved -- looks like an interesting learning/development experience!  But if you just want a segmented display attached I'd try hard and see if you can get an I2C one from somewhere.

Comment: @goldilocks any idea about this raw 7segment display ? I just received it now after weeks of waiting from the seller :) Do you think it's going to be impossible to wire it to the Pi without using 20% of the CPU? Why is it so? Is it such a time-consuming task to light a few LEDs?

Comment: IMO it should not be, but I'm a programmer and not an electrician, lol.  That blog (2nd paragraph after the pic, "To drive the display...") describes something that sounds like a refresh rate, which has to be high enough to avoid visible flicker.  I do not know why that's necessary -- I would have hoped you could just turn an LED segment on and leave it on.    You might ask on [E.E.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) about that.

Comment: Actually reading the paragraphs after that it sounds like it is a power issue and there's only one pin driving them??  What the heck are all the other wires for?  I should have been an electrician.  You get to go outside more.

Comment: Multiplexing is a way to reduce the amount of I/O needed. If you don't count the decimal point, each digit has 7 LEDs and there are four digits. This means you'll need 28 I/O lines and 1 common connection to GND or VCC (common cathode or common anode) to control each LED without multiplexing.

Comment: You could multiplex this in a row and column fashion with 7 rows (connect each digit's segment "A" to row 1, segment "B" to row 2, etc...) and four columns (connected to each digit's common line). You just went from 28 I/O lines to 11. To refresh the display, output the first digit on the rows to set the necessary LEDs on and off then toggle the column output for digit 1. Repeat for digit 2, 3, and 4 then back to digit 1. If you do this quickly enough it appears that all four digits are continuously lit when they are in fact only on one digit at a time.

Comment: Would this one work without hassle ? http://www.ebay.fr/itm/4-Bit-LED-Affichage-Display-Module-Circuit-Board-Tube-Digital-Pour-Arduino-DIY-/331351380200?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_71&hash=item4d2614d0e8   (there seems to be 2 chips under the PCB, in the bottom pictures)

Comment: @Basj the problem you may run into with anything marketed to Arduino is that most Arduino logic is +5VDC and the RPi is +3VDC. You'd need to check the specs to see if this module works with 3 volt logic. (I took a longer look at the link you provided and it appears this board will work down to 3 volts with reduced LED intensity). Good luck and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hopefully my last edit, after an even longer look, I don't recognize the signals as they are called out on the board and can't tell if this is a SPI or I2C interface. If it uses a non-standard interface you'll be writing your own driver software too.

Answer (score 1):

These two pages may help:

- http://rpi.science.uoit.ca/lab/ssdispay/
- http://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/170pt-projects/driving-a-seven-segment-four-digit-display

They don't contain the code you exactly want, but they are the best I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning - if you don't find a suitable package that interfaces with it, it's more than feasible to just *write your own*.

Just define your own `SegmentDisplay.Print(int)` function, which parses the number (I heavily suggest using integer division and modulo to find each digit!) and toggling each GPIO pin to match the number.  It might be a bit of tedious work at the start, but it would allow you to recycle code from project to project, as well as help simplify your code down the line.

Comment: I could go that way of course (it shouldn't be too difficult to display digit by selecting the right LEDs!). But before trying: 1) How are the pins routed? I see 12 pins on this display, and there are at least 7 * 4 = 28 segments / LEDs to be set on/off. How is done the multiplexing?         2) Do you think it will be heavy for CPU to light all these LEDs ? Does it need continuous action to keep a LED on?

Comment: @Basj 1) According to [the image](http://www.greenforcecells.com/fimage/4digit.jpg) that comes with the eBay listing you've posted, it seems like all four digits share the same 8 pins to light the individual LEDs on the digit.  The other four pins on the piece simply select which digit to be lighting.  You'll want to not only set the 8 per-digit LEDs the way you want, but also set the three digits you're not trying to set to HIGH output to prevent electrons from flowing through that digit, and the one you're setting to LOW output to bring electrons in.

Comment: @Basj 2) It looks like you'll need to cycle through all four digits on each call to your new `SegmentDisplay.Print(int)` method, but also need to call that new method 60 times per second - you might be able to get away with fewer if you're okay with flickering.  Because you're using Python, I can imagine it being a bit of a CPU suck.

Comment: So this means we need lots of realtime action to always keep the right digits on or off? Impossible to set some LEDs on, and then wait without doing anything?

Comment: @Basj - yes, that is indeed what you'll need to do.  You might be able to get away with keeping one single digit on and letting the CPU sleep, but if you're using two digits or more, you'll need to flick between the digits rapidly enough to fool the human eye... which means CPU time.

Comment: Why can't we cycle the 4 digits *once* every second, wouldn't the 28 LEDs keep their previous status ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22494/discussion-between-basj-and-sctjkc01).